# users store a string separated by characters in a table

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that gets data from a field in a database, such as `"Daniel , Camilo ; Francis ;"`

I need to store them in a new table, which is not like walking the string and get the names by cutting by the character `';'` Or go cutting the string, no matter what the string is modified, only will use the table.

Comment: What you mean by _only will use the table_?

Comment: I want to separate string names and store them in an empty table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

Try [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You can pass array of all possible separator characters as a parameter.

```
Dim value As String = "Daniel , Francis ; One , Two , Four , Five ; Ten"
Dim separatedValues as String() = value.Split({","c, ";"c})
```

Then you can use array of separated values for adding in then new table

Comment: hmm okay, but I just need to be separated by ";" , and the amount of string names is dynamic , bone can be more than 3

Comment: Then use only one character in the parameter `String.Split(";"c)`. Amount of the names doesn't metter